# SIGSEGV errors using shared objects between c++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, swig

I got a problem for a couple of weeks now and I need to know if my intuition is right. My Android app is using a c++ library and SIGSEGV errors are triggered every once and awhile.

I got a NetworkThread written in c++, it receives Update object from a server. I got a WorkerThread written in Java, it asks the NetworkThread if there's new updates every 0.5 s.

I used JNI wrappers generated with SWIG to communicate between c++ and Java.

In the NetworkThread we have a `std::vector` containing all new updates.

The WorkerThread (Java) use this line to get a new Update object :

```
Update u = nwt.nextUpdate();
```

Then this trigger in the NetworkThread (c++) the following code :

```
Update NetworkThread::nextUpdate() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&nwt_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&inQ_mutex); // RACING CONDITION
    Update c = inQ.front();
    inQ.erase(inQ.begin());
    if (inQ.size() <= QUEUE_SIZE) {
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&inQ_threshold_cv);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&inQ_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&nwt_mutex);
    return c;
}
```

The line `Update c = inQ.front();` make a shallow copy of the object (Update doesn't override the = operator). I think this is bad because Update contains reference to other object (and vectors of Objects).

Then the line `inQ.erase(inQ.begin());` is called, from std::vector's documentation the element removed are destroyed. **Does that mean at this point the references to the objects and the vectors inside c are not valid anymore ?**

After the Update object is sent back to Java with this JNI snippet :

```
    // Retrieve the current JNIEnv* with the cached JVM
    int status;
    JNIEnv* env;
    bool isAttached = false;

    status = gCachedJVM->GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_2);
    if(status < 0) {
        status = gCachedJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        if(status < 0) {
            return;
        }
        isAttached = true;
    }

    jmethodID update = env->GetMethodID(gClazzUpdateListenerWrapper, "update", "(J)V"); // J stands for Java long type

    // Call Java method update from jUpdateListener object
    env->CallVoidMethod(jUpdateListener, update, (jlong)(intptr_t)&u); // Pointer as agument, we'll build the Update object in Java

    if (isAttached) {
        gCachedJVM->DetachCurrentThread();
    }
```

Here I send to Java an address (long), and I build the object like this (I use the default constructor generated with SWIG) :

```
    Player p1;

public void update(long ptrUpdate) {
    final Update u = new Update(ptrUpdate, false);
            p1 = u.getEntity(0).toPlayer();
            ...
    }
```

**Is it a bad practice to do this like I do ?** I think doing this with a long is bad but if the address is allocated and valid there shouldn't be any problem right ?

Anyway this seems to work well until I got a SIGSEGV error (no further informations) which I suspect is because I keep using reference to objects that have been destroyed and collected.

Comment: Is what I think right or wrong ? (bold questions)